# How can an Oracle-user query a table in another schema in oracle18c?

Tags: sql, oracle, permissions, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle18c

I want the oracle-user **c##user2** to query the table **test** in the schema **c##user1**, but when I query the table, I get the message "no rows selected".

Both users have the permissions "CREATE SESSION" and "CREATE TABLE".

I gave **c##user2** the select-permissions on the above table using:

```
GRANT SELECT ON c##user1.test TO c##user2;
```

The table **test** has 2 rows. When I query the table as **c##user1**, I get the expected result of 2 rows.

I query the table as **c##user2** using:

```
SELECT * FROM c##user1.test;
```

I expect to see the 2 rows, but instead I only get "no rows selected". What steps am I missing?

Comment: Your code looks perfectly fine. Are you sure that there are 2 records in test table? Have you recently inserted the records in the same session and committed the transaction? May be commit was not executed.

Comment: That was the case, thank you.

Comment: In that case, accept the answer so that it is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in comment, giving answer to mark this question as resolved.

You need to do `commit` after DML statement so that the changes are visible in other sessions.

Cheers!!